# NUMA Support on WIndows 7

Tags: windows, hardware, numa

I recently read about NUMA support on Win7 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/aa363804(v=vs.85).aspx) and as I'm allocating a lot of HEAP Mem and sharing it between multiple Processes this sounds like a good thing to use.
Unfortunately my system doesn't seems to support NUMA as when i run:

```
ULONG HighestNodeNumber;

if (0 == GetNumaHighestNodeNumber(&HighestNodeNumber))
{
    //ERROR!
}
 if (0 == HighestNodeNumber)
{
    cout << "Not a NUMA system - exiting";
}
```

HighestNodeNumber will always be 0. I ran through my BIOS Settings but I could find anything that would enable NUMA.

It says on WIkipedia: " Intel announced NUMA compatibility for its x86 and Itanium servers in late 2007 with its Nehalem and Tukwila CPUs." [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access] which is why i assumed that my CPU MUST have NUMA support (which might have been a bit naive).

I'm running on a HP machine (BIOS ver 68SCF Ver. F.50) with Win7 and an Intel Core i5-2540M.

What am I missing out?

Comment: Your CPU may have NUMA support, but that would be irrelevant whilst you only have *one* CPU.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying!